# How to Enabling ckEditor on Android and IPhone Browsers

Tags: android, iphone, mobile, ckeditor, editor

I'm trying to enable ckeditor on devices like android and iPhone, but didn't show up on any browsers like chrome android browser uc browser opera and safari and also it is showing up on computer browsers?

1. Download the latest version (default build) of ckeditor
2. Open ckeditor.js file in notepad (placed at the root of ckeditor folder)
3. Find  the statement:
   `if(e.webkit)a.indexOf("chrome")>-1?e.chrome=true:e.safari=true;`
4. Add the following statement in front of the above statement:
   `if(e.chrome)e.mobile=false;`
5. Save and upload it on your server
6. CKEditor will be working now on your Android Browser

I have followed this step, but still not working on mobile phone browsers?

**here the solution of it**

here solution for you just need to change or updated you ckeditor.js file to latest ckeditor.js file

[here link of latest ckeditor.js](https://cdn.ckeditor.com/4.5.10/standard/ckeditor.js)

here screenshot

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I don't know where did you get those instructions, but they are too complicated and forces you to keep changing the source files whenever you update.

Instead you should follow the official advice at http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/dev_unsupported_environments

```
<script src="ckeditor/ckeditor.js"></script>
<script>
    CKEDITOR.env.isCompatible = true;
</script>
```

Comment: Do you want me to install cakephp to test it?

Answer (score 0):

just add this line in your script  then it is working for all devices in

CKEDITOR.env.isCompatible = true;

```
       CKEDITOR.env.isCompatible = true;
         CKEDITOR.replace('jobdescription', {
           width: '100%',
           height: 300
         });
```

refer the below link
https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor4/latest/guide/dev_unsupported_environments.html